# DateTime.Now based timer not tracking correctly over multiple instances

Tags: c#, timer, uwp

this is my first proper C# application that I wrote to help me at work (I'm on helpdesk for an MSP with a passing interest in scripting and code) and I'm using UWP just to make it look pretty without much effort. Our time tracking software is a web service written in ASP.Net so generally the built in timer is fine but it won't survive a browser refresh, so I wrote my own that fits into the format that we need for our tickets.

I have taken some code from other Stack questions and my dad (A C# framework dev for a multinational) helped re-write some of the timer code so it wasn't using stopwatch. He just isn't available to fix this issue at the moment. I do understand how it works now, just not how to debug the issue I'm getting.

It supports multiple timers running at the same time and creating a new timer auto-pauses all others. It handles two time formats, minutes and decimal hours, so that will explain some of the properties you see in the code.

My issue is that when I add a new timer, it pauses all others, but then when I press start on an older timer (Returning back to an earlier ticket) the time instantly jumps up to how long the new timer was running for, with about 10% difference (It's never exactly how long it was running).

This is the class that tracks notes and the current time (Tidied up a bit for neatness):

```
public sealed class JobTimer:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private DateTime _created; // When the timer was created
    private DateTime _started; // When it was most recently started
    private TimeSpan _offset; // The saved value to offset the currently running timer
    Timer _swTimer; // The actual tick that updates the screen

    public JobTimer() : this(TimeSpan.Zero)
    { }

    public JobTimer(TimeSpan offset)
    {
        _offset = offset;
        _created = DateTime.Now;
        IsNotLocked = true;
    }

    // Time in seconds
    public string TimeMin => string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", ElapsedTime.Hours, ElapsedTime.Minutes, ElapsedTime.Seconds);

    // Time in decimal hours
    public string TimeDec => string.Format("{0}", 0.1 * Math.Ceiling(10 * ElapsedTime.TotalHours));

    public DateTime Created => _created;

    public TimeSpan ElapsedTime => GetElapsed();

    public void Start()
    {
        _started = DateTime.Now;
        _swTimer = new Timer(TimerChanged, null, 0, 1000);

        NotifyPropertyChanged("IsRunning");
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        if (_swTimer != null)
        {
            _swTimer.Dispose();
            _swTimer = null;
        }

        _offset = _offset.Add(DateTime.Now.Subtract(_started));

        NotifyPropertyChanged("IsRunning");
    }

    private TimeSpan GetElapsed()
    {
        // This was made as part of my own debugging, the ElaspsedTime property used to just be the if return
        if (IsRunning)
        {
            return _offset.Add(DateTime.Now.Subtract(_started));
        }
        else
        {
            return _offset;
        }
    }

    // Updates the UI
    private void TimerChanged(object state)
    {
        NotifyPropertyChanged("TimeDec");
        NotifyPropertyChanged("TimeMin");
    }

    public bool IsRunning
    {
        get { return _swTimer != null; }
    }

    public void ToggleRunning()
    {
        if (IsRunning)
        {
            Stop();
        }
        else
        {
            Start();
        }
    }
}
```

This goes into the ViewModel:

```
public class JobListViewModel
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<JobTimer> _list = new ObservableCollection<JobTimer>();

    public ObservableCollection<JobTimer> JobTimers => _list;

    public JobListViewModel()
    {
        AddTimer();
    }

    public void AddTimer()
    {
        JobTimer t = new JobTimer();
        JobTimers.Add(t);
        t.Start();
    }

    public void PauseAll()
    {
        foreach(JobTimer timer in JobTimers)
        {
            timer.Stop();
        }
    }

    // Other functions unrelated
}
```

And this is the UI button click that adds a new timer

```
    private void AddTimer_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Create JobTimer
        ViewModel.PauseAll();
        ViewModel.AddTimer();

        // Scroll to newly created timer
        JobTimer lastTimer = ViewModel.JobTimers.Last();
        viewTimers.UpdateLayout();
        viewTimers.ScrollIntoView(lastTimer);
    }
```

I realise it's a lot of code to dump into a post but I can't pinpoint where the issue is being caused. I was able to find that something alters the offset when I hit the AddTimer button whether the existing timer is running or not, but I can't find what's altering it.

Comment: Lacking a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, it may not be possible to say for sure what the bug is. However, why was it a goal in the first place to implement this without `Stopwatch`? If you are expecting to start and stop timers, I would think that would be the simplest, most reliable way to implement it. It appears right now you are trying to track the total duration of when a timer has been paused and subtracting that from the net time. What's the point of that when there's a perfectly usable class that has the start/pause/stop functionality built-in?

Comment: I can zip the code up if you want to run it local. I can reproduce every time in UI but I don't know where to put my break point. The reason for going away from `Stopwatch` was because it doesn't have to be ms accurate and I need to be able save to file and then load (Thus the `_offset` property). Using `DateTime.Now` to get started and then getting another `Now` and subtracting the started time gives me the total running time, not total time paused. It also means I can save the `TimeSpan` as text and load it again later without writing a wrapper for Stopwatch.

Comment: Also my dad when we went through this initially said there was a limit to the number of Stopwatches you can have in a program and you can't dispose them the same way as a timer, though he suspects it has changed in a recent version. The only practical difference for my use case is that DateTime is less performance heavy but not as accurate if trying to get performance metric.

Comment: _"I can zip the code up if you want to run it local"_ -- no, that's not what you need to do. You need to read [mcve] and follow the guidelines there. See also [ask], along with the articles linked at the bottom of that page. (FWIW, I'm not aware of any limitation on the number of `Stopwatch` instances you can have...AFAIK, they effectively encapsulate a single performance counter in the same way you're trying to encapsulate `DateTime.Now` here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After building enough other code to support the code you posted, I was able to reproduce your problem.

The issue in your code is that you unconditionally call the `Stop()` method, whether the timer is already stopped or not. And the `Stop()` method unconditionally resets the `_offset` field, whether or not the timer is already running. So, if you add a timer when any other timer is already stopped, its `_offset` value is incorrectly reset.

IMHO, the right fix is for the `Start()` and `Stop()` methods to only perform their work when the timer is in the appropriate state to be started or stopped. I.e. to check the `IsRunning` property before actually doing the operation.

See below for an actual [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) version of the code you posted, but without the bug.

In addition to fixing the bug, I removed all of the unused elements (that is, all the code that did not appear to be used or discussed in your scenario) and refactored the code so that it is more idiomatic of a typical WPF implementation (see helper/base classes at the end). When I run the program, I am able to start and stop the timer objects without any trouble, even after adding new timers to the list.

Notable modifications:

- Use of `NotifyPropertyChangedBase` class as base class for model classes.
- Leverage of said base class features for property change notification, by keeping public properties as simple value-storing properties modified as needed.
- Use of `ICommand` implementation for user actions (i.e. "commands").
- Separation of timer-specific start/stop functionality when adding timers from view-specific scrolling-into-view behavior.
- Remove time-formatting logic from non-UI model object, and put it in the XAML instead
- Use conventional (and more readable) `-` and `+` operators for `DateTime` and `TimeSpan` math

**JobTimer.cs:**

```
class JobTimer : NotifyPropertyChangedBase
{
    private DateTime _started; // When it was most recently started
    private TimeSpan _offset; // The saved value to offset the currently running timer
    Timer _swTimer; // The actual tick that updates the screen

    private readonly DelegateCommand _startCommand;
    private readonly DelegateCommand _stopCommand;

    public ICommand StartCommand => _startCommand;
    public ICommand StopCommand => _stopCommand;

    public JobTimer() : this(TimeSpan.Zero)
    { }

    public JobTimer(TimeSpan offset)
    {
        _offset = offset;
        _startCommand = new DelegateCommand(Start, () => !IsRunning);
        _stopCommand = new DelegateCommand(Stop, () => IsRunning);
    }

    private TimeSpan _elapsedTime;
    public TimeSpan ElapsedTime
    {
        get { return _elapsedTime; }
        set { _UpdateField(ref _elapsedTime, value); }
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        _started = DateTime.UtcNow;
        _swTimer = new Timer(TimerChanged, null, 0, 1000);
        IsRunning = true;
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        if (_swTimer != null)
        {
            _swTimer.Dispose();
            _swTimer = null;
        }

        _offset += DateTime.UtcNow - _started;
        IsRunning = false;
    }

    private TimeSpan GetElapsed()
    {
        return IsRunning ? DateTime.UtcNow - _started + _offset : _offset;
    }

    // Updates the UI
    private void TimerChanged(object state)
    {
        ElapsedTime = GetElapsed();
    }

    private bool _isRunning;
    public bool IsRunning
    {
        get { return _isRunning; }
        set { _UpdateField(ref _isRunning, value, _OnIsRunningChanged); }
    }

    private void _OnIsRunningChanged(bool obj)
    {
        _startCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        _stopCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }
}
```

**MainViewModel.cs:**

```
class MainViewModel : NotifyPropertyChangedBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<JobTimer> JobTimers { get; } = new ObservableCollection<JobTimer>();

    public ICommand AddTimerCommand { get; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        AddTimerCommand = new DelegateCommand(_AddTimer);
        _AddTimer();
    }

    private void _AddTimer()
    {
        foreach (JobTimer timer in JobTimers)
        {
            timer.Stop();
        }

        JobTimer t = new JobTimer();
        JobTimers.Add(t);
        t.Start();
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainViewModel model = (MainViewModel)DataContext;

        model.JobTimers.CollectionChanged += _OnJobTimersCollectionChanged;
    }

    private void _OnJobTimersCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ObservableCollection<JobTimer> jobTimers = (ObservableCollection<JobTimer>)sender;

        // Scroll to newly created timer
        JobTimer lastTimer = jobTimers.Last();
        listBox1.ScrollIntoView(lastTimer);
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```xml
<Window x:Class="TestSO46416275DateTimeTimer.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:l="clr-namespace:TestSO46416275DateTimeTimer"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Window.DataContext>
    <l:MainViewModel/>
  </Window.DataContext>

  <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type l:JobTimer}">
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElapsedTime, StringFormat=hh\\:mm\\:ss}"/>
        <Button Content="Start" Command="{Binding StartCommand}"/>
        <Button Content="Stop" Command="{Binding StopCommand}"/>
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>

  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Button Content="Add Timer" Command="{Binding AddTimerCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    <ListBox x:Name="listBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding JobTimers}" Grid.Row="1"/>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

**NotifyPropertyChangedBase.cs:**

```
class NotifyPropertyChangedBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void _UpdateField<T>(ref T field, T newValue,
        Action<T> onChangedCallback = null,
        [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, newValue))
        {
            return;
        }

        T oldValue = field;

        field = newValue;
        onChangedCallback?.Invoke(oldValue);
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**DelegateCommand.cs:**

```
class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action _execute;
    private readonly Func<bool> _canExecute;

    public DelegateCommand(Action execute) : this(execute, null)
    { }

    public DelegateCommand(Action execute, Func<bool> canExecute)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null || _canExecute();
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute();
    }

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Comment: Apologies for my example code, I now see the difference. I did clean up some debug stuff and bits that weren't relevant to how the clock works but I can see the difference. I'll be sure to remember for next time! And thank you very much for your example. When I read your first paragraph I checked my code, tested the `_offset = _offset.Add` part inside the if statement and it worked as I expected as a quick fix. I will definitely see how to implement your other changes once I start to understand how they work. Being able to write code is easy but writing it to standard is something I'm learning