# C# Updating a Elapsed Time Variable to Hold Value

Tags: c#, timer, stopwatch

I'm working on a Stop Watch assignment where we have to make our own stop watch class; i.e I cannot use StopWatch. I have a timer updating for every second with which updates the label. What can I do to my class so that it keeps the elapsed time when I stop then start again? Currently it just goes back to 00:00:00. Keep in mind this is an assignment which is why it's not the most logical way to do this.

```
public class Time
{
    //fields
    DateTime startTime, stopTime, currentTime;
    bool isActive = false;
    bool hasStarted = false;


    public string ElapsedTime
    {
        get
        {
            // TODO: return something if never started..
            if (isActive == false && hasStarted == false)
            {
                //Exception ex = new Exception("Please start the timer."); // This should be in the StartClock method.
                //return ex.ToString();

                return "00:00:00";
            }
            // TODO: return something if running...
            else if (isActive == true && hasStarted == true)
            {
                return DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
            }
            // return if started then stopped (I did this one for you)
            else
            {
                return (stopTime - startTime).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
            }
        }
    }

    public void StartClock() // Good! The "else" is where you should be throwing the exceptions
    {
        //TO DO: set the startTime
        if(!isActive)
        {
            isActive = true;
            hasStarted = true;
            startTime = DateTime.Now;
        }
        else
        {
            Exception ex = new Exception("Please start the timer."); // This should be in the StartClock method.
        }
    }


    public void StopClock()
    {
        //sets stop time
        if(isActive && hasStarted)
        {
            isActive = false;
            stopTime = DateTime.Now;//something else
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know why it (initially) returns 0 after you execute `startClock()` again? Think about what you would have to do to reset it back to 0 if you are allowed to call stop/start multiple times.

Comment: "I did this one for you" hahahaha

Comment: Side note: you're dealing with "logged" events ("I was started at", "I was asked for the current time at"), so you should be getting the time in UTC: `DateTime.UtcNow` (although the base C# library's handling of date/time/zone is poor in some areas, :sigh:).  Also, read your exception message in `StartClock` again... does it seem strange to you?  And what does it not actually do?

Comment: There are too many possible ways to answer this. Your question is too broad. That said, one obvious way is to maintain a running total, updated every time the timer is stopped, which you add to the current elapsed time (which would be computed for a running timer based on the most recent start time and the current time). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46416275/datetime-now-based-timer-not-tracking-correctly-over-multiple-instances) for someone else's nearly-working example of code that works that way.

Comment: I apologize for the broad example I just have a bit of strict guideline for the project pertaining to fields and props. Much easier when I'm allowed freedom. I'll attempt some answers thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try keeping track of the total elapsed time, here's some pseudocode that'll maybe help:

this.elapseTime = 00:00:00;

startClicked: 
     this.startedTime = Now()

stopClicked:
    this.elapsedTime += Now() - this.startedTime

getCurrentElapsedTime:
    return this.elapsedTime + Now() - this.startedTime